# Props is (sometimes only) undefined in React Native. TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I came upon a strange bug today.
I am using a  component called while loading first in App.js, where it works fine.
I am logging props, all fine: an object.
Then, navigating to next component, LogInScreen.js using React Navigation, there props is undefined.
So, if  called from App.js, it works, props is an object, and called from LogInScreen.js it crashes (props is undefined).
If I try to destructure it, or call a member `props.isNotFullScreen` it crashes with the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isNotFullScreen' of undefined`

The only workaround I found was to write `const isNotFullScreen = props ? props.isNotFullScreen : false;`
but still I am interested if one of you has an idea what is happening.

I am using React Native 0.63.3 testing with iOS simulator

[image: Calling from App.js]

[image: Calling from LogInScreen.js]

[image: logs show props correctly then undefined]

[image: Simulator error]

Here is my Spinner component

```
import React from "react";
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles/SpinnerStyle";
import { Colors } from "../themes";

const Spinner = (props) => {
  console.log("Spinner props:", props);
  const { isNotFullScreen } = props;
  console.log("isNotFullScreen:", isNotFullScreen);
  return (
    <View style={[styles.spinner, !isNotFullScreen && styles.fullScreen]}>
      <ActivityIndicator
        animating={true}
        size="large"
        color={Colors.baseBlue}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Spinner;
```

Comment: I didn't understand how you're passing your props to the ```Spinner``` component. Can you explain with more details?  The only prop I can see you're passing is the ```isInApp```.

Comment: That is correct, I sometimes pass props, like ` isInApp` which was just for testing purposes or most correctly `isNotFullScreen`, and sometimes I don't. However it should not be undefined even if I pass nothing, it should be an empty object, right?

Comment: Try to put the code you get the ```isNotFullScreen``` prop inside an ```useEffect``` hook. Like ```useEffect(()=>{    console.log("Spinner props:", props);
  const { isNotFullScreen } = props;
  console.log("isNotFullScreen:", isNotFullScreen) }, [])```. That it will make it work.